# How can I prove that this is a martingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> We define $S_0=0$ and $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$ where $(X_n)$ is an i.i.d. sequence such that $\Bbb{P}(X_1=-1)=\Bbb{P}(X_1=1)=1/2$. We define $\mathfrak{F}_n=\sigma(S_0,...,S_n)$. I want to show that $(P(S_n,n))_{n\geq 0}$ is an $\mathfrak{F}_n$-martingale ($P$ is a polynomial in 2 variables) if for all $l,m\in \Bbb{Z}$ $$P(l+1,m+1)-2P(l,m)+P(l-1,m+1)=0$$

I know that I need to show that $\Bbb{E}(P(S_{n+1},n+1)|\mathfrak{F}_n)=P(S_n,n)$ somehow I don't see how to work with the polynomial case, how can I split this up to get somehow a sum of conditional expectations? I know that this has to do with the equality from above. Could someone maybe give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_n$, while $S_n$ is  $\mathscr{F}_n$-measurable. It follows that for any measurable (and admissible) $f$, [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768648/a-question-about-conditional-expectations?noredirect=1) $E[f(S_n,X_{n+1})|\mathscr{F}_n]=E[f(s,X_{n+1})]|_{s=S_n}$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}E[P(S_{n+1},n+1)|\mathscr{F}_{n}]&=E[P(S_{n}+X_{n+1},n+1)|\mathscr{F}_{n}]=\\
&=\frac{1}{2}P(S_{n}+1,n+1)+\\
&+\frac{1}{2}P(S_{n}-1,n+1)=\\
&=\frac{1}{2}2P(S_n,n)=P(S_n,n)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: But why do you leave the $X_{n+1}$ away in the second equality? Because I see that you apply somehow the assumption but I would have applied it with $k=S_n+X_{n+1}$ and $n_*=n+1$

Comment: @cristallo The full step-by-step is
$$\begin{aligned}E[P(S_n+X_{n+1},n+1)|\mathscr{F}_n]&=E[P(s+X_{n+1},n+1)]|_{s=S_n}=\\
&=(P(X_{n+1}=1)P(s+1,n+1)+\\
&+P(X_{n+1}=-1)P(s-1,n+1))|_{s=S_{n}}=\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(P(S_n+1,n+1)+P(S_n-1,n+1))\end{aligned}$$

Comment: @cristallo conditional expectations and their properties are usually treated as prereqs to martingale theory. If this is the case for you, then this should be all fine.