# Specified random walk is a Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ and $(Z_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be sequences of $\mathbb{N}_0$ valued random variables with relationship

$X_n-X_{n-1}=
\begin{cases} Z_n-1 \quad&\text{ if } X_{n-1}\geq 1\\
Z_n  \quad\quad &\text{ if } X_{n-1}=0\end{cases}$

If $Z_n$ is i.i.d with distribution $p$ then $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov chain with the following transition matrix.
\begin{equation}
\Pi(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
      p(y) &\text{ if } x=0\\
      p(y-x+1)      &\text{ if } x\geq0,y\geq x-1 \\
      0 &\text{ else }\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
My idea to prove it:
If
$ X_n\geq 1$ then 
$P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}\lvert X_n=x_n,...,X_0=x_0)=P(Z_n-1+X_n=x_{n+1}\lvert  X_n=x_n,...,X_0=x_0)=p(x_{n+1}-x_n+1)$
If
$X_n=0$
$P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}\lvert X_n=x_n,...,X_0=x_0)=P(Z_n+X_n=x_{n+1}\lvert  X_n=x_n,...,X_0=x_0)=p(x_{n+1})$

Is this correct ?

Comment: And what is $X_n-X_{n-1}$ if $X_{n-1}\in (-\infty,0)\cup(0,1)$? Is it $0$?

Comment: $X_n$ and $Z_n$ are $\mathbb{N}_0$ valued. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suppose $X_0=0$. Rewrite $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ as
$$\begin{aligned}X_n&=(X_{n-1}+Z_n-1)\mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}(X_{n-1})+(X_{n-1}+Z_n)\mathbf{1}_{\{0\}}(X_{n-1})=\\
&=:h(X_{n-1},Z_n)\end{aligned}$$
Let $\mathscr{F}_n:=\sigma(X_k,k\leq n)$. Now note that $X_n$ is a function of $(Z_1,...,Z_n)$ so $Z_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_{n}$. Then by using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768648/a-question-about-conditional-expectations?noredirect=1)
$$\begin{aligned}P(X_n\in B|\mathscr{F}_{n-1})&=E[\mathbf{1}_B(h(X_{n-1},Z_n))|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]=\\
&=E[\mathbf{1}_B(h(x,Z_n))]|_{x=X_{n-1}}=\\
&=E[\mathbf{1}_B(h(X_{n-1},Z_n))|X_{n-1}]=\\
&=P(X_n\in B|X_{n-1})\end{aligned}$$
for all Borel $B$. So $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a Markov chain. Now note again
$$P(X_n=y|X_{n-1}=x)=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{y\}}(h(x,Z_n))]$$
So if $x=0$
$$E[\mathbf{1}_{\{y\}}(h(0,Z_n))]=\sum_{z\geq 0}\mathbf{1}_{\{y\}}(0+z)P(Z_1=z)=P(Z_1=y)$$
while if $x \geq 1$:
$$E[\mathbf{1}_{\{y\}}(h(x,Z_n))]=\sum_{z\geq 0}\mathbf{1}_{\{y\}}(x+z-1)P(Z_1=z)=P(Z_1=y-x+1),\,y\geq x-1$$